# How to create a data extension with everyone who has ever opened or clicked on an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, error-messages, id, number, key

I'm trying to create a data extension with everyone who has ever opened or clicked on an email in it...

The challenge is, that we used to have a SFDC + ExactTarget integration prior to migrating to MarketingCloud fully.

The _Open and _Click tables have SubscriberKey data which was populated by SFDC and is a hexadecimal as well as SubscriberKey data populated by SFMC which is an email address (our primary identifier).

As such, the data is a bit useless using SubscriberKey as identifier and I want to use the Subscriber ID.

However, when creating a target data extension i'm running into an issue where it is not recognizing that i have specified the field type as being 'number' and is providing me with an error suggesting it isn't referencing a number field to the Subscriber ID...

Any idea how to resolve?

A.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write the [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) like this:

```
select
x.subscriberid
, s.emailaddress
from ( 

  select
  o.subscriberid
  from _open o 
  where o.isunique = 1

  union

  select distinct
  c.subscriberid
  from _click c
  where c.isunique = 1

) x
inner join _subscribers s on (s.subscriberid = x.subscriberid)
```

The target Data Extension would have these columns

- SubscriberID, Number
- EmailAddress, EmailAddress

Comment: Be aware as well that this will only be for the last 6 months as that is all that the data views track back to.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for the speedy response!so is there a way to do this for greater than 6months? For 6months and less we are able to use the measures approach and we're really looking for the >6Month data

Comment: If you need more than 6 months of data, you'll (unfortunately) need to create your own DEs for the data and extract and import tracking data.